# Keep Strings into .txt file or put them into a Database?

Tags: android, database, performance, text-files

Hey, I have a lot of Strings that I use into my app, the .txt file that I use has ~14000 lines.. and each 3-10 lines are divided into sections like `<String="Chapter I"> ... </String> ..`

Speaking of performance/speed, should I put the sections into a Database, Or read line by line through the .txt file and check if the section number is the current one? Will this affect speed/performance?

I could also divide each ~2000 lines into a different .txt file so there would be less lines to go through. Is this a bad way of storing data? Thanks

Comment: create a JSON formatted file. parse the JSON into data model classes and insert them into the database

Answer (score 1):

I think [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/about.html) would do the trick. It will probably be way faster than parsing a text file, plus you wont have to maintain the headache of your own ad hoc text database, or build a parser in the first place. Basically, use it, its way easier.

Comment: Android has builtin SQLite libraries. Use them. It has column index functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to deal with Strings in Android is to put them into res/values/strings.xml (I'm pretty sure you can have multiple String files in that directory if you like). If you are developing in Eclipse it will automatically populate the R class (the resource class) with constants that you can use to reference these Strings in your code:

```
R.string.mystring
```

Or in XML layouts:

```
@string/mystring
```

Or if you're doing something more custom you can use:

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello);
```

I would definitely choose this over a .txt file. It's much easier. All the work is done for you! Have a read of [this Android article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a database is for. Use it.